# spring integration 2 soap calls database

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-integration

I am new to spring integration and learning in the process.
I will have to make two SOAP calls.
1st SOAP call --->use the 1st call response as 2nd SOAP request.
And programmatically get the url and other request parameters from the database.

I was successfully able to make the call with this configuration

```
<int-ws:outbound-gateway id="Service" request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel" uri="http://localhost:8080/core/v1" marshaller="marshaller" unmarshaller="marshaller"/>
```

I haven't used any activators or interceptors. just used xml and gateway interface. I have hardcoded the request values.
Can someone help me how to get values from database and build this in a much better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JDBC Outbound Gateway to retrieve data an pass it into WS Outbound Gateway.

You can find some samples on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jdbc

Comment: Thanks Artem for the quick reply. For my second part of the question how should i pass the response from the 1st call as request to the second SOAP call. The response from the 1st call is a list and i have to iterate through the list and call the second SOAP call.

Comment: You can use splitter to iterate and transformer to build a new request

Comment: Hi Artem, I am trying to implement the change and having issues on how to pass the JDBC outbound gateway response to pass it into WS outbound gateway. Could you give an example for the same

Comment: Not sure what you expect from me, but SOAP is based on the XML, so you have to build one based on the result of the JDBC call and pass it into WS Outbound Gateway. Some WS sample is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ws-outbound-gateway